# One To Many mapping return invalid column name

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api

I am creating a one to many relationship between two entities using ef core with fluent API, but it throws the error

> Invalid column name 'UploadAttemptStatusId'.

I have tried using the data annotation attribute as well as the `.HasForeignKey` method.

```
public class UploadAttempts : BaseEntity
{
    public Guid UploadedAttemptId { get; set; }
       
    public string ClientFileName { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDateTimeUtc { get; set; }
    public Guid UploadingUserId { get; set; }
    public int UploadAttemptStatusId { get; set; }
    public virtual UploadAttemptStatusDictionary UploadAttemptStatusDictionary { get; set; }
}

public class UploadAttemptStatusDictionary : BaseEntity
{
    public int UploadAttemptStatusId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UploadAttempts> UploadAttempts { get; set; }
}


public void Map(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    var entity = modelBuilder.Entity<UploadAttemptStatusDictionary>();

    //set table name
    entity.ToTable("Upload_attempt_status_dictionary");

    entity.Property(t => t.UploadAttemptStatusId).HasColumnName("Upload_attempt_status");
    entity.HasKey(t => t.UploadAttemptStatusId);

    entity.Property(t => t.Description).HasColumnName("description").IsRequired();
    entity.HasMany(t => t.UploadAttempts).WithOne(t=>t.UploadAttemptStatusDictionary);
}


public void Map(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            var entity = modelBuilder.Entity<UploadAttempts>();

            //set table name
            entity.ToTable("Upload_attempts");

            entity.Property(t => t.UploadedAttemptId).HasColumnName("upload_attempt_id");
            entity.HasKey(t => t.UploadedAttemptId);
            
            entity.Property(t => t.ClientFileName).HasColumnName("client_filename");
            entity.Property(t => t.UploadingUserId).HasColumnName("uploading_user_id");
            entity.Property(t => t.CreationDateTimeUtc).HasColumnName("creation_datetime_utc");

            entity.HasOne<UploadAttemptStatusDictionary>(t => t.UploadAttemptStatusDictionary)
                .WithMany(t => t.UploadAttempts)
                .HasForeignKey(t => t.UploadAttemptStatusId);
        }
```

Comment: Where are getting the error ? You have **UploadAttemptStatusId** in both tables. maybe the exception is regarding to another table.

Comment: Remove `entity.HasMany(t => t.UploadAttempts).WithOne(t=>t.UploadAttemptStatusDictionary);` line from the first map. Relationships should be configured in one place to avoid conflicting mappings. Also make sure the model and database are in sync (if you do `Add-Migration`, it should be empty. And all current migrations should be applied.)

Answer (score 0):

I have updated entities like below and it works, but it is not as per FluentAPI convention.

As per FluentAPI convention, we should not have to map foreign key in mapper, it should get mapped directly using .HasOne() or .HasMany() methods.
But in my case this was achieved by this line in UploadAttemptsMap

```
entity.Property(t => t.UploadAttemptStatus).HasColumnName("upload_attempt_status");
```

```
public class UploadAttempts : BaseEntity
    {
        public Guid UploadedAttemptId { get; set; }
        public string ClientFileName { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreationDateTimeUtc { get; set; }
        public Guid UploadingUserId { get; set; }
        public int UploadAttemptStatus { get; set; }
        public virtual UploadAttemptStatusDictionary UploadAttemptStatusDictionary { get; set; }
    }

public class UploadAttemptStatusDictionary : BaseEntity
    {
        public int UploadAttemptStatus { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<UploadAttempts> UploadAttempts { get; set; }
    }

public void Map(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            var entity = modelBuilder.Entity<UploadAttempts>();

            //set table name
            entity.ToTable("Upload_attempts");

            entity.Property(t => t.UploadedAttemptId).HasColumnName("upload_attempt_id");
            entity.HasKey(t => t.UploadedAttemptId);

            entity.Property(t => t.UploadAttemptStatus).HasColumnName("upload_attempt_status");
            entity.Property(t => t.ClientFileName).HasColumnName("client_filename");
            entity.Property(t => t.UploadingUserId).HasColumnName("uploading_user_id");
            entity.Property(t => t.CreationDateTimeUtc).HasColumnName("creation_datetime_utc");

            entity.HasOne<UploadAttemptStatusDictionary>(t => t.UploadAttemptStatusDictionary)
                .WithMany(t => t.UploadAttempts)
                .HasForeignKey(t => t.UploadAttemptStatus);
        }

public void Map(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            var entity = modelBuilder.Entity<UploadAttemptStatusDictionary>();

            //set table name
            entity.ToTable("Upload_attempt_status_dictionary");

            entity.Property(t => t.UploadAttemptStatus).HasColumnName("upload_attempt_status");
            entity.HasKey(t => t.UploadAttemptStatus);

            entity.Property(t => t.Description).HasColumnName("description").IsRequired();
            entity.HasMany(x => x.UploadAttempts);
        }
```